# Compilation issue when using blocks with LLVM GCC 4.2

Tags: objective-c, ios4, llvm, objective-c-blocks, llvm-gcc

I wrote a gist a while ago: https://gist.github.com/611157. It compiled and worked ok.

I came back to it recently and it no longer complied.

I noticed it compiles with LLVM 2.0 with no problems or warnings (and then runs and works!)

With LLVM GCC 4.2 it fails to compile.
I get the following error

```
error: incompatible block pointer types initializing 'signed char (^)(struct objc_object *, struct NSString *)', expected 'BOOL (^)(struct objc_object *, struct objc_object *)'
```

I have the feeling I have a declaration missing or wrong, but I don't know, so I thought I would ask.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Show your Block and variable declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your block has type:

```
BOOL (^blockRelationship)(id,id)
```

but the second parameter in both the initialisation and the parameter type in the method declaration is NSString*

Change your block definition to

```
BOOL (^blockRelationship)(id,NSString*)=^(id obj,NSString* relationship) { ... } ;
```

I've tested the above in GCC 4.2, GCC 4.2 LLVM and Clang LLVM 1.6.

With the `id` second parameter, in the first two cases I got your error appearing on both the initialisation line and the line where it is passed as a parameter to `toDictionaryBlockingRelationships:`  In the Clang case I got no error at all.

With `NSString*` as the second parameter, there were no errors in all three compilations.